# Associated models 1:M SequelizeDatabaseError: column [Model].id does not exist

Tags: sequelize.js

So I have two tables, one with a list of users, then another with associated accounts. So for example, one user might have two accounts. Also, several users might be associated with overlapping accounts.

I have a belongsTo and a hasMany, as I've done in the past.

but when I try to get the associated accounts, I'm getting back an error stating Accounts.id is not found.

Association:

```
Accounts.belongsTo(Users,{foreignKey: 'uid'})
Users.hasMany(Accounts, {foreignKey: 'uid'})
```

uid is a primaryKey on the User table. There are no primary keys on the Accounts table.

Models:

Users

```
db.define('users', {
  uid: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  login_count: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  approved: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  last_login_ip: {
    type: Sequelize.INET,
  }
});
```

Accounts:

```
db.define('accounts', {
  uid: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT
  },
  account_num: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT
  },
  token: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});
```

Comment: can you add all model definition as well?

Comment: done @Anatoly! Added above.

Comment: And where is a model that is a link between users and accounts?

Comment: @anatoly I don't have one. I'd think that the primary key in Users matches the uid in accounts. Is that not enough?

Comment: (I just noticed I had the models labeled wrong. It's fixed now.)

Comment: !!! belongsToMany!

Answer (score 0):

Gotta use a Junction/Through table

belongsToMany

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships